# How to place website logo and identity image design on the very top of email sent via phpmailer to gmail

Tags: phpmailer

[enter image description here][1]I am sending a password recovery mail and i used table html tag for cross-platform support. I put the image in the right position in the mail, which is at the top. But the image was placed below the message as attachment without the css style and not within the table row on top of the page. How do ensure the image is placed at the top not bottoom inside gmail?

I used phpmailer AddEmbeddedImage('../../img/kokwo_full.png', '{$site}', '{$site}.png').

````
$subject="Password Reset Request - {$site}";

$message="
<table  width='100%' style=' background:#f2f2f2; margin:0px; margin:0px 0px; color:#fff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:0% 2%'>
<tr style='background:#fff;'>
<td colspan='2'><img src='{$http}://{$website}/img/kokwo.png' style='background:#4885ed; height:60px'/></td>
</tr>

<tr style='height:140px;'>
<td colspan='2' style='color:#000;text-align:center; font-size:32px'> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan='2' style='color:#000;text-align:center; font-size:32px; border-bottom:1px solid #000'> Hi {$user_name},</td>
</tr>
<tr style='  height:90px;'>
<td colspan='2' style='color:#000; font-size:18px'>Instant password change
<p style='color:#000; font-size:10px'>{$email}</p></td>
</tr>
<tr style=' color:#808080; '>
<td colspan='2' style='color:#808080; font-size:18px'>Click on this button</td>

</tr>

<tr style='  height:30px;'>
<td colspan='2' style='text-align:center;'>
<form action='{$http}://{$website}reset' method='post' class='regi' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='text'  name='user_id' value='{$user_id}' style='display:none;'/>
<button type='submit' style='background:#00A9E0; color:#fff; padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
 border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
    width: 89%;
    margin:25px 3%'   name='reg_user' >Change your password on ".ucwords($site)." </button>
</form>
</td>
  </tr>
<tr style='height:80px;'>
<td colspan='2'> </td>
</tr>
<tr style='height:30px; background:#4885ed;'>
<td colspan='2'></td>
</tr>

</table>
";
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
if (isset($_POST['reset-password'])) {

require '../../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require '../../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.{$site}.com"; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails




$mail->Username = $my_mail;
$mail->Password = $my_password;



$mail->From = $my_mail;
$mail->FromName = $fromname;

$mail->addAddress($email, $user_name);


$mail->addReplyTo($my_mail, $fromname);
$mail->Sender=$my_mail;

//Provide file path and name of the attachments



$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../../img/kokwo_full.png', '{$site}', '{$site}.png');
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AltBody=$subject;
$mail->Send();


if (!$mail) {

        array_push($errors, "<div class='error'><p>
        Could not be delivered to {$email},please try again
            .</p></div>");



    } else {
     array_push($errors, "<div class='success'><p>
             Check inbox or spam folder  at {$email}.</p></div>");


        }
}
```what i want to achieve[What I got][2]


  [1]: https://kokwo.com/img/stack/real.jpg
  [2]: https://kokwo.com/img/stack/fake.jpg
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have attached it as an embedded image, but you're not actually using it in your template.

The second parameter to `addEmbeddedImage` is `cid`, a content identifier. A separate problem is that you have single-quoted your strings, so no variable interpolation will be done - that's probably not what you intended.

So if your call looks like this:

```
$mail->addEmbeddedImage('../../img/kokwo_full.png', 'kokwo', 'kokwo.png').
```

you would use that image in your HTML like this:

```
<img src="cid:kokwo" style="background:#4885ed; height:60px">
```

Note that the string after the `cid:` part of the URL exactly matches the `cid` value you passed to `addEmbeddedImage`.

Comment: Thanks. The cid and embedded image worked perfectly. The images was shown. The problems is that the image was show  at the bottom instead of at the top. The image at the bottom was displayed like attachment and isolated not within even within table element. I want in inside table row at the top within the web identities elements. Thanks